# Ionic caching custom requirement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am working on a ionic project.

I am facing issue of caching the view.

Let's take an example. There are three views A, B, C.

Requirements :

1. When I go from A to B, B should load ignoring the cache.
2. If I go from B to C then back to B from C page should get cached (View B has searching functionalities so need to be cached with search result).
3. If I go back to A and return to B page should get reload.

Here View B get cached for all for both A to B and C to B.

Is there way to clear cache for a particular view while moving on one view to another?

I want to clear cache of View B on forward but cached on backward.

I tried this but it didn't work for me :

```
$stateProvider.state("app.B", {
    url : "/B",
        views : {
            "content" : {
                templateUrl : "app/modules/B/B.html",
                controller : "BController"
            }
        },
        cache : true
    });

function BController($scope, $timeout, $ionicHistory) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
        viewData.fromCache = false;
    }); 

    ......
}
```

Comment: That's not as specific as what you're looking for, but the only "documented" way I know is using [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/).clearCache(). However, it clears the full cache (not for a specific view).

Comment: It sounds like you want to cache the search results not the view itself right?  Why do you want to cache the actual view?